# Converting a method that borrows an item into one that takes ownership over it

Tags: rust

I want to know if rust can automatically coerce a function that implements `Fn(&X) -> Y` into a function that implements `Fn(X) -> Y`.

More specifically, I have a higher-order function with the following signature:

```rust
fn do_stuff<Y, F: Fn(i32) -> Y>(action: F) {
    // Does some stuff with the method (specifically, move it into a Box)
}
```

and I want to be able to call it like so:

```rust
do_stuff(i32::to_string)
```

instead of the current

```rust
do_stuff(|x| x.to_string())
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

> expected function signature `fn(i32) -> _`,
>
> found function signature `for<'r> fn(&'r i32) -> _`.

I figure this is because the function `i32::to_string` borrows `&self` as a parameter, while the closure takes ownership over it.

Is there a way that I can change the signature of `do_stuff` so that I can also call it in that way?

---

[Here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3341c6da597740ddd3407914e696576c) is a reproduction of the issue in the rust playground.

Comment: Your code compiles and runs fine. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=44a5a350c3fc19b182c45af67ad202f0

Comment: @Finomnis Weird. It is simplified a bit from my real code, I will find the difference that changes this behaviour and update the question

Comment: Removing the `borrow-checker` tag because this is a type error, not a borrow checker error. (Those are piled onto you _after_ you've fixed all the type errors ;))

Comment: Here is a playground with an instance of this going wrong: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6c335a96e923f74047f3eee97d9fbb26

Comment: @Finomnis I have fixed the accidental typo that made this compile. The issue is still the same - but the code from before worked simply because `X` was `&i32`, meaning that `F: Fn(&i32) -> Y` instead of what I wanted (which is to make `F: Fn(i32) -> Y` even in this case)

Comment: Good question. I'm not aware of any good way to make that work. My code also has those little seemingly useless lambdas in many places.

Comment: @Finomnis it seems to have been re-opened, so no worries :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to implicitly coerce `Fn(&T) -> U` into `Fn(T) -> U`, because it's just not among the implicit coercions Rust will allow. However, there is a way to factor out the repetitive code:

```rust
fn add_ref<T, U>(f: impl Fn(&T) -> U) -> impl Fn(T) -> U {
    move |ref x| f(x)
}
```

It works on (a minimized version of) your example:

```rust
fn do_stuff<Y, F: Fn(i32) -> Y>(_: F) {}

fn main() {
    do_stuff(add_ref(i32::to_string))
    // do_stuff(i32::to_string)
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this would fail
}
```

see [the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6cb641cdc78cd17d1a5dd3c366aa34a6).

Answer (score 3):

Technically this works:

```rust
use std::borrow::Borrow;

fn do_stuff<X, Y, F: Fn(X) -> Y>(action: F)
where
    X: Borrow<i32>,
{
    // Does some stuff with the method (specifically, move it into a Box)
}

fn bla(x: i32) {}
fn bla_ref(x: &i32) {}

fn main() {
    do_stuff(i32::to_string);
    do_stuff(bla);
    do_stuff(bla_ref);
}
```

Although it's pretty much normal to use the `|x| x.do_something()` closures regularly, so I wouldn't worry about it too much.

Comment: Interesting, if I wanted to call this `action` (inside the `do_stuff` method), how could I go about it? Considering it gets as an input a different generic type

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really follow how this works. What I'm struggling to understand is why I can't create a new struct `A` that implements `Borrow<i32>`, and thus it means that I will have to feed `action` an instance of `A` (which is clearly not an `i32`). Something like so: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=882adcad41ba53826ace3cae37882ad7

Comment: Wouldn't it make invoking `action` impossible since we don't know the concrete type behind this trait?

Comment: I think I got you wrong then, all you mentioned is what functions you want to feed into `do_stuff`, but you never mentioned what you actually want to do with it then. The problem is that if your function signature could be `&i32` or `i32`, it's very hard to write code that could feed both of them. Casting **away** from those types is easy, because they both implement `Borrow<i32>` and can therefore be cast to a `&i32`, but there is nothing really that can be cast **into** both of them.

Comment: It's especially hard if you think about ownership: One carries a lifetime and the other does not. That alone means that there probably isn't a trait that can unify them for casting another type **into** them. For example, let's assume we start with a `i32`. Creating an `i32` from an `i32` is easy, we simply `.copy()`. Creating a `&i32` is also easy, we can simply borrow the `i32`. But we can't borrow an `i32` into an `i32`, and we can't clone an `i32` into a `&i32`, because one owns, and the other one references. It simply isn't compatible, and so I don't think you will find a solution here.

Comment: The only way this would ever work is if you could retrieve an `X` object somehow without explicitely having to construct it, like from another function that returns an `X`. But I can't currently think of a way to describe `X` with traits so that it could always be created from an `i32` and be an `i32` or a `&i32`.

Comment: Oh I see, I get what you are saying - it makes sense that one cannot treat a `i32` and `&i32` variables in the same way...

Comment: I almost managed to get it working by deriving a custom trait that I then implemented for `Fn(i32)` and `Fn(&i32)` differently, but apparently one cannot impl for all types of those two traits because the compiler can't guarantee that there isn't a type that implements both. So after a couple of hours of trial end error, I gave up and came to the conclusion that it probably isn't possible in current Rust. Although I would also be interested in a solution if there is any :)